# M.2 to mini PCIE

Tags: embedded, pcie, sbc, m.2

I have an SBC with the following configuration on the M2 port
[image: M.2 Mux Diagram]

If I require a mini PCIE device is it sufficient to make a breakout board and match pin to pin? We have a pcb engineer to handle the high frequency considerations, I just need to know if the protocol is compatible